# Unversioned build in Travis CI

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

Why does Travis CI add an additional Node.js build with anonymous version, and then uses Node.js 0.10.x to build it?

This is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: node_js
sudo: required
dist: trusty
matrix:
  include:
    - node_js: "0.10"
      script: "npm test"
    - node_js: "0.12"
      script: "npm test"
    - node_js: "4"
      script: "npm test"
    - node_js: "6"
      script: "npm run travis"
addons:
  postgresql: "9.5"
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database pg_promise_test;' -U postgres
  - node test/db/init.js
env:
  - BLUEBIRD_DEBUG=0
```

And this is my Travis CI build log:

```
1563.1 linux Node.js
1563.2 linux Node.js: 0.10
1563.3 linux Node.js: 0.12
1563.4 linux Node.js: 4
1563.5 linux Node.js: 6
```

The first item always comes up as an extra build that I do not need, since I already specify Node.js 0.10 in my `.travis.yml` file.

Is there a way we can get rid of that auxiliary build?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4681.

Edit: This does not work:

Have not tried it, but you might get rid of the extraneous build with adding an `exclude` block:

```
language: node_js
sudo: required
dist: trusty
matrix:
  include:
    - node_js: "0.10"
      script: "npm test"
    - ...
  exclude:
    - language: node_js
...
```

Comment: This change results in `ERROR: An error occured while trying to parse your .travis.yml file.`. See https://travis-ci.org/vitaly-t/pg-promise/builds/153840739

Comment: Alright, then `language: ...` is so crucial to the config, that the workaround to the same problem but to the key `compiler: ...` does not apply here. You might want to add your experience to the referenced ticket.

Comment: I can't really make sense out of reply there... What did I do wrong?

Comment: You do nothing wrong. There is a bug. The workaround as reported in the bug  report, does unfortunately not apply to your use case.